# How to execute background task in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, iphone, swiftui

My goal is to execute background task in SwiftUI.

What I've tried:

1. use background task, but the task does not get executed.

My expectation: the task gets executed.

My actual result: The task does not execute.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct WeatherAppApp: App {
    @StateObject private var imageStore = ImageStore()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(imageStore: imageStore)
        }
        .backgroundTask(.appRefresh("randomImage")) {
            await refreshAppData()
        }
    }
    
    func refreshAppData() async {
        print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function) triggered")
        
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "A Random Photo is awaiting for you!"
        content.subtitle = "Check it now!"
        
        if await fetchRandomImage() {
            try? await UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "test", content: content, trigger: UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)))
        }
    }
    
    func fetchRandomImage() async -> Bool { // async random fetch image
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://picsum.photos/200/300"),
              let (data, response) = try? await URLSession.shared.data(from: url),
              let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 200 else {
            return false
        }
        
        imageStore.randomImage = UIImage(data: data)
        
        return true
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI
import BackgroundTasks

class ImageStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var randomImage: UIImage?
}

extension ImageStore {
    static let shared = ImageStore()
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var imageStore: ImageStore
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Button("Local Message Autorization") {
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { success, error in
                    if success {
                        print("All set!")
                        
                    } else if let error = error {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
            }.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                .padding()
            
            Button("Schedule Background Task") {
                let request = BGAppRefreshTaskRequest(identifier: "randomImage") // Mark 1
                request.earliestBeginDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .second, value: 2, to: Date()) // Mark 2
                do {
                    try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request) // Mark 3
                    print("Background Task Scheduled!")
                } catch(let error) {
                    print("Scheduling Error \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
                
            }.buttonStyle(.bordered)
                .tint(.red)
                .padding()
            
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(imageStore: ImageStore.shared)
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/starting_and_terminating_tasks_during_development tasks are not guaranteed to run at a specific time but you can trigger during development